# What does "&key" means in PHP?

Tags: php, keyword

I have a very weird problem. I am using PHP, in my PHP code, I wrote the email content and generated this link:

```
....
<a href="http://www.domain.com/act.php?id=' . $userid . '&key=' . $actkey . '">http://www.domain.com/act.php?id=' . $userid . '&key=' . $actkey . '</a>
....
```

Most of the time, it works fine. Then, I receive lots of complaints saying they can't activate. After checking their emails, I found this:

```
<a href="http://www.domain.com/act.php?id=20090=hsdf87hsf89sd">http://www.domain.com/act.php?id=20090=hsdf87hsf89sd'</a>
```

The "&key" is missing. Why? Very weird bug!!!

The full PHP command:

```
$content = '<div style="font-family:Calibri; color:#333;">
    Hi there, <br><br>

    Thank you for register to our website, click the following link to activate your account:<br><br>

<a href="http://www.domain.com/act.php?id=' . $userid . '&key=' . $actkey . '">http://www.domain.com/act.php?id=' . $userid . '&key=' . $actkey . '</a><br><br>

XXX Team</div>';
```

Gumbo could be right, my email content is HTML-based:

```
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
```

Comment: I think you have a quoting problem. Can you post the full PHP command that leads to that string?

Comment: edit your question, and post how you generate the link

Comment: @Pekka: I checked my quoting, it seems fine. The weird thing is, why most of the time were fine. So weird
@Pentium10: I edited my question, please take another look
@Jon: Thanks. I love this site. The response is incredibly fast. Amazing!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to encode the `&` character with a [character reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.3) like `&amp;`:

```
'<a href="http://www.domain.com/act.php?id=' . $userid . '&amp;key=' . $actkey . '">http://www.domain.com/act.php?id=' . $userid . '&amp;key=' . $actkey . '</a>'
```

Or better:

```
'<a href="' . htmlspecialchars('http://www.domain.com/act.php?id=' . $userid . '&key=' . $actkey) . '">' . htmlspecialchars('http://www.domain.com/act.php?id=' . $userid . '&key=' . $actkey) . '</a>'
```

Comment: But that can hardly be his problem, can it? The `&` should show up in his source code nevertheless, shouldn't it?

Comment: & is a query string seperator - url encoding it would get the wrong effect .. he's trying for `page.php?id=5&key=7&someother=52` - the literal ampersand is correct

Comment: @Erik: No, we’re in the HTML context. There the `&` needs to be expressed with a character reference.

Comment: Actually I thought i was losing my mind, but it works both ways: `http://pixel.dyndns.info/tests/test.php` - I never realized you could have escaped `&`, but it works without it escaped also, which is why its not what his problem is.

Comment: @Erik: It may work for *key*. But it is invalid and may not work for other names.

Comment: Yep, its invalid; I just read the specs and tried it in a validator - I've used it wrong literally 100's of times without error, nice to know =x

Comment: so whats the conclusion? If i changed the "&" to "&amp", will it solve my problem? I am abit confused now.

Answer (score 0):

`&key` used as string, eg. `echo '&key';`, doesn't mean anything special - it's just a normal string. Could you paste your whole code?

The problem might be that `&` character is special character in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Put key in the first place:

```
<a href="http://www.domain.com/act.php?key=' . $actkey . '&id=' . $userid . '">http://www.domain.com/act.php?key=' . $actkey . '&id=' . $userid . '</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Gumbo is right about encoding `&` as &amp; within an HTML document.
You can let PHP's [http_build_query()](http://docs.php.net/http_build_query) do all the encoding necessary to build a valid query string.

```
/* testdata: */ $userid=12; $actkey='abc&def';
$params = http_build_query(array(
  'id'=>$userid,
  'key'=>$actkey
), '', '&amp;');
$url = 'http://www.domain.com/act.php?'.$params;
echo $url;
```

prints `http://www.domain.com/act.php?id=12&amp;key=abc%26def`